# How to use different size image set according the screen size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I used this code below to use different size image set for different screen size, it works good in firefox and chrome but not wordks in safari. Is there any solution? My code:

```
<picture>
<img src="static/images/content/roni.jpg"
srcset="static/images/content/roni_mobile.jpg 420w,
        static/images/content/roni_landscape.jpg 700w,
        static/images/content/roni_tablet.jpg 1056w,
        static/images/content/roni.jpg 1937w"/>
</picture>
```

I want solution using html/css/js

Answer (score -1):

Use Media tag with size and use below code

```
.blogpost img {
width:55%;
min-width:220px;
}

.blogpost img {
width:100%;
max-width:600px;
}
```

Comment: is there any solution using js? i have 4 set of image in different size. i want to use this for desktop, tablet, mobile and mobile landscape.

Comment: Your example isn't a complete answer. If I use it as is, it won't solve the OP's original question